# Extracting the text starting with a character and ends with another into new column in python

Tags: python, pandas, find, extract, extend

I am trying to extract an ID from a link given in a column.

ID started after "tt" and ends before "/". Trying to extract it into new column.

Input dataset:

| Movie | Link |
| --- | --- |
| movie 1 | [http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1|](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1%7C) |

output dataset:

| Movie | Link | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| movie 1 | http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1 | 114709 |

Comment: is the ID column supposed to be empty?

Comment: No. It should be filled with 114709. Edited and updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the link, use a regular expression with `str.replace`:

```
df['Link'] = df['Link'].str.replace(r'(.*/title/tt)(\d+)(/.*)', r'\1\2\3/ \2')
```

If as I believe, your example is incorrect and you want in fact to create a new column with the number:

```
df['ID'] = df['Link'].str.extract(r'(?:.*/title/tt)(?P<ID>\d+)(?:/.*)')
```

output:

```
     Movie                                                   Link       ID
0  movie 1  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1|  0114709
```